# Android Studio Error: 9,13 16,17 23,9

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebaseui

Today I want to build an app with the Firebase Ui for android. As I build the App there are some Errors:

```
Error:(16, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable FirebaseAuth
Error:(9, 13) error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseAuth
Error:(23, 9) error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseUser
```

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you posted your error and code as text, instead of an image...

Comment: yeah but is is a text. Not a code. If you build an app it says Error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following lines of code:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

In your build.gradle file.

Comment: +1 Thanks :D The erros are away. But now it says

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.

Comment: +1 Okay Now: Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gm:play-services-auth:11.6.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Janla/Desktop/Verzeichniss/Privat/Scripts/LundusChat/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>